# Cannot upload Image file to the server using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to upload `image` to the `server` using Volley `StringRequest`. Earlier i did it using VolleyPlus's `SimpleMultipartRequest` and it was working fine. But now i change hosting and and because of some encoding it is not accepting data of `SimpleMultipartRequest` so now i have to send it using `StringRequest` but it is not uploading. Or i have to add something in php because now it is getting string request and not the multipart request.

```
 String filepath;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

   final Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("image"));
    filepath = getPath(Upload.this, imageUri);

   btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            caption = txtCaption.getText().toString();
            if (filepath != null){
                progressDialog.show();
                imageUpload(filepath);

            }else {
                Toast.makeText(Upload.this, "Image not Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
 }

private void imageUpload(final String imagePath){
     StringRequest smr =  new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, IMAGE_UPLOAD_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(String response) {
                 Toast.makeText(Upload.this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 progressDialog.dismiss();
                 finish();
         }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(com.android.volley.error.VolleyError error) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     }){
         @Override
         protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
             Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
             // the POST parameters:
             params.put("uploadedfile", imagePath);
             params.put("userid", userid);
             params.put("caption", caption);
             params.put("product","normal");
             return params;
         }
     };

     MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(smr);
 }
 public String getPath(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    //copy file and send new file path
    File TEMP_FILE = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/My Children");
    TEMP_FILE.mkdir();
    String fileName = getFileName(contentUri);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fileName)) {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd_hhmmss");
        String timestamp = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());

            userid = SharedPreferenceManager.getmInstance(Upload.this).getMobileno();

        File copyFile = new File( TEMP_FILE + userid +".jpg");
        copy(context, contentUri, copyFile);
        return copyFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    return null;
}

public static String getFileName(Uri uri) {
    if (uri == null) return null;
    String fileName = null;
    String path = uri.getPath();
    int cut = path.lastIndexOf('/');
    if (cut != -1) {
        fileName = path.substring(cut + 1);
    }
    return fileName;
}

public static void copy(Context context, Uri srcUri, File dstFile) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(srcUri);
        if (inputStream == null) return;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dstFile);
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**MyApplication class**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
public static final String TAG = MyApplication.class.getSimpleName();
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

private static MyApplication mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
}
```

**PHP script**

```
<?php

$uploaddir = 'ImagesUpload/';

$userid=$_POST['userid'];
$caption=$_POST['caption'];
$category=$_POST['product']; 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
else
{
    $sql = "SELECT ImgID FROM ImgInfo WHERE UserID ='$userid' ORDER BY ImgUploadDate DESC LIMIT 1"; 
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $tempID=$row["ImgID"];
     }
    $nxtIndex=(int)(substr($tempID,strpos($tempID,"I")+1,strlen($tempID))+1);
    $imgID=$userid."I".$nxtIndex;
} 
else 
{
    $imgID=$userid."I1";
}
        $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]=$imgID.".jpg";
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
        if (copy($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
        {
        $filename="ImagesUpload/".$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];     
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ImgInfo (UserID,ImgCategory,ImgLink,ImgID,ImgUploadDate,ImgCaption) VALUES ('$userid','$category', '$filename','$imgID',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'$caption')";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
            {
              if ($category=='Profile')
                {
                 $resultreturn = array();
                 array_push($resultreturn,array('PPurl'=>'http://smilestechno.000webhostapp.com/'.$filename));
                 echo json_encode(array("result"=>$resultreturn),JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;    
            }
        $conn->close();
    }
    else 
    {
    echo "Upload failed";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: where is exception/log?

Comment: There is no exception or error, But php responding with Upload Failed.

Comment: It's bit easy with use of *okHttp* library instead it's bit simple did you tried with that ?

Comment: No i didnt, but okHttp is complicated then Volley in string request